# How to handle the loop_stop() Paho MQTT

Tags: python, loops, mqtt, mosquitto

I try to connect small model cars via MQTT to a broker. Every time they pass a certain section (piece == 20 here) of the track, they connect to the broker, subscribe, send a message with the current position. After they received a message from the broker, they should disconnect from the broker. This works quite well so far, but only the first time they cross the piece == 20. As soon as the client (car) is disconnected and the loop is terminated with loop_stop(), nothing happens any more if they cross the section again. If I don't disconnect and stop the loop, everything works fine - but I want that they disconnect and stop the loop. 
Have you got an idea what's the problem here?

```
from overdrive import Overdrive
import time
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
```

class Auto:

```
def __init__(self, macaddr):
    self.car = Overdrive(macaddr)
    self.client = CarClient(macaddr)
    self.check = 0


def startEngine(self):


    self.car.changeSpeed(300, 1000)
    self.car.setLocationChangeCallback(self.locationChangeCallback) # Set location change callback to function above


def locationChangeCallback(self, addr, location, piece, speed, clockwise):

    if piece == 20 :

        self.client.run(piece)
```

class CarClient:

```
def __init__(self, id):
    self.client = mqtt.Client(id)
    self.id = id


def on_connect(self, mqttc, obj, flags, rc):
    print("connected" + str(rc))

def on_message(self, mqttc, obj, msg):
    print("received message" + " " + str(msg.payload))
    self.client.disconnect() #if i remove this and the following line, everything works fine
    self.client.loop_stop() #but i have to disconnect and stop the loop after they received a message


def on_publish(self, mqttc, obj, mid):
    print("Data published " + str(mid))

def on_subscribe(self, mqttc, obj, mid, granted_qos):
    print("Subscribed: " + str(mid) + " " + str(granted_qos))

def on_log(self, mqttc, obj, level, string):
    print(string)

def run(self, position):

        self.position = position

        self.client.on_message = self.on_message
        self.client.connect("localhost", 1883, 60)  # connect to broker
        time.sleep(0.1)
        self.client.subscribe("test_channel")  # subscribe topic
        self.client.loop_start()

        self.client.publish("test_channel1", "ID:" + str(self.id) + " Position: " + str(position))
```

Main()

```
def main():

  bmw = Auto("D8:4E:11:7C:25:BD")
  bmw.startEngine()


if __name__ == '__main__' :
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the problem. The function to stop the loop is not called loop_stop() its called loop.stop().

So the code segment has to be changed to the following:

```
def on_message(self, mqttc, obj, msg):
    print("received message" + " " + str(msg.payload))
    self.client.disconnect()
    self.client.loop.stop()
```

thanks anyway

Comment: No, it's definitely [loop_stop()](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python/blob/master/src/paho/mqtt/client.py#L1827)

Comment: Why are you trying to disconnect the mqtt client when it receives a message? Why do you expect the client to be able to continue to receive messages once you disconnect it from the broker?

Comment: Because I try to code kind of a real life scenario. A car comes to a crossing, subscribes a topic and publishes his position/speed data via MQTT to a „intersection control logic“. The logic handles the data, calculates the speed with which the car can cross the intersection without a collision and returns it to the car. After the car crossed the intersection it should disconnect as there is no need for it to stay connected. The code should be able to handle a disconnection as the method run() is executed every time the car drives in a special track segment. In the upper case piece == 20

Comment: That's no reason to disconnect, just unsubscribe to the relevant topic

Comment: This means that a car in the real world would be connected to one and the same server all the time? Isn't this kind of unrealistic? In my opinion a car should cross a contact-loop on the street, gets the address of the server via RFID, connects and subscribes, publishes the data to the server. The server calculates the speed of the car and publishes the speed adaption for collision prevention back to the car. As soon as the car crossed the intersection it should unsubscribe and disconnect. Do you understand now what I mean?I hope its a little bit clearer now what i try to code

Comment: No, I expect a client to stay connected to a single broker (probably load balanced) for an entire journey that way it can send/receive messages at any time about multiple things, not just about a single junction. Your design is not a reflection of the real world.

Comment: Fair enough, but back to the code. Isn't there a problem if i don't quit the loop I started with loop_start? I mean everytime my car passes piece == 20 and calls the run() - method, a new loop (thread) will be started?

Comment: Also there is no need to stop the client loop even if you want to disconnect, you can reuse the same loop when you next call connect. Just start it once up front (inside the init funtion) and carry on as normal.

Comment: Its working now. I do it the way you told me to do. So I connect in the __init__ method of the CarClient class and just unsubscribe after I received a message - don‘t disconnect as I did it before.
Thanks a lot.